# Solution for local "database" containing huge text and .SQL files

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, text-files

I have a few hundred gigabytes of text data contained within a single directory tree. This data is comprised of both very large text files and a few MySQL database dumps (which for the most part, of course, function as text files when outside of the DBMS they came from). The structure of the data within the text files varies wildly, with some being single record per line, some having columns and all kinds of column separators, and a few that even appear to be JSON.

My usual method of searching this large but primitive database is to do a `grep` at the parent folder, but the database is now large enough that a single `grep` command can take as much as 30 minutes.

For this reason, I'm long overdue a move to a proper database solution.

All the data is stored on my local machine and I will be the only user, hence my requirements for a solution would be as follows:

- That I can point it to my parent directory to index all the text files in it, giving me the ability to search through them as fast as possible
- That I don't have to learn a language just to search the database - a GUI for searching is preferable, but a CLI would also be acceptable
- That I don't have to setup and run an entire server just to access it (unless there is no such thing as a serverless DBMS and this is absolutely inescapable)
- A nice bonus, but not necessary: that I can search through files using  their columns, even when between them they have inconsistent separators

Does a database management solution that would fulfil those needs exist, or am I asking for too much here?

Apologies for any sort of naivete or false assumptions in this question; databases are simply something my needs have forced me to look into, rather than anything that I necessarily know much about.

Comment: I dont think you are asking for a database, I think you are looking for an indexing solution that would allow full text search of arbitrary files. If it were a database yuo would usually be importing the files into the database, which doesnt sound like a good fit given the nature of the files you have.

Comment: @TomC Interesting, I'd always assumed that databases were capable of working from an existing directory structure, and I wasn't even aware indexing as a separate solution was a thing. If indexing is what I'm looking for, do you know of any that would work for me?

Comment: I did a quick google search for indexing solutions. There are quite a few.

Comment: Essentially a database is a logical data structure over a physical file system  Depending on the product some RDBMS platforms (such as Oracle) can work with OS files but it's not their core capability. What you want is a search engine over a local index, I guess Elasticsearch is probably the market leader but the FOSS candidate is [Lucence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Lucene)

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac See here: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13830/suspended-when-the-user-who-instigated-the-problem-was-not.